# Prevent child element from collapsing with twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following list:

- Root

  - Child1
  - Child2

The root should be collapsible but not the children. With the following code both will collapse if I click on one of them. How can I accomplish to prevent children from being collapsed?

```
<li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#root"><a href="#">Root</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="root">
        <li><a href="some_url">Child1</a></li>
        <li><a href="some_url">Child2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Edit: Better approach to describe what I want.

1. Root is collapsed from start. If I click on root it should show the children (works with code above) and if I click root again it should hide the children (works too)
2. Once children are displayed I click on a child. This click will trigger collapse and hides the children again. (this is what I'm trying to prevent)

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/4537/

Comment: Why you are trying to collapse root ?

Comment: can you show jsfiddle of your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move the `data-toggle` and `data-target` attributes to the `a` element, like

```
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#root">Root</a>
    <ul class="nav nav-list collapse" id="root">
        <li><a href="#">Child1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Child2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Having them in the topmost `li` element makes that element and all its children catch the click events and trigger the collapse. Putting the attributes to a child element limits the scope of the click events handling to just that element (and its children.)

Comment: This is a nice workaround for this particular case, but  the general question, "is it possible to avoid children elements triggering the collapse?" remains unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're trying to do is prevent `#root` from minimizing when one of its children  `li` is clicked? If so, what you're looking for is [event.stopPropogation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation).

Try adding the following code to your JSFiddle:

```
$('ul > li').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
```

This targets the child `li` elements, and prevents their click events from bubbling up to the parent `li` with collapse attributes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#root a").click(function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `li` tags are descendants of the `ul#root` there is no way to collapse root without collapsing the child `li` elements.  When root is collapsed the child `li` tags will not be visible.