# How to disable the toggle if someone clicks this bootstrap li submenu

Tags: bootstrap-4

The problem is that when the submenu li is clicked then the whole thing collapses.
What should happen is that only when the parent is clicked then only the menu should expand or collapse not when the sub-menu items are clicked.

```
<ul id="menu-content2" class="menu-content collapse show">
  <!-- Single Item -->
  <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#clothing">
    <a href="#">clothing</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu collapse show" id="clothing">
      <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bodysuits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hoodies &amp; Sweats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jackets &amp; Coats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pants &amp; Leggings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rompers &amp; Jumpsuits</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shirts &amp; Blouses</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sweaters &amp; Knits</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xh0ur8kb/

Comment: You have to move your `data-toggle` and `data-target` to the `<a>` element, so child clicks do not trigger it. If you want to keep it in `<li>`, you have to use a little JS. See here for more detailed answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687960/prevent-child-element-from-collapsing-with-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks this solved it- 
`<a href="#"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#clothing">clothing</a>`